# Unexpected behaviour modifying CSS height via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu, which is a list of items. Clicking on an item makes it "active" (adds the `active` class to it), and should toggle the visibility (in this case, the `height`) of the other items.

For legacy reasons, there are 2 listeners for the click event (I know).

My problem is that when clicking on an item, the previous items do not disappear. E.g. if I click on item 3, items 1 and 2 do not disappear, although their height is set to 0. Please run the following snippet which will hopefully be clearer than my explanation:

```js
$('#menu>li').on('click', function(e) {
 $('#menu>li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('#menu>li').on('click', function(e) {
 if (!e.originalEvent) return;
  var clickedItem = e.currentTarget;
  console.log('Clicked on', clickedItem)
  $('#menu>li').each(function (x, i) {
   console.log(x, i)
    var li = $(i);
    if (!li.hasClass('active')) {
      var newHeight = li.height() <= 0 ? '40px' : '0';
      console.log('setting', newHeight);
      li.height(newHeight);
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

li {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  height: 0;
}

li.active {
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="listElement active">Test me 1</li>
  <li class="listElement" style="padding-left:70px">Test me 2</li>
  <li class="listElement" style="padding-left:140px">Test me 3</li>
  <li class="listElement" style="padding-left:210px">Test me 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want? I added "overflow: hidden;" in your "li" css:

```js
$('#menu>li').on('click', function(e) {
 $('#menu>li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('#menu>li').on('click', function(e) {
 if (!e.originalEvent) return;
  var clickedItem = e.currentTarget;
  console.log('Clicked on', clickedItem)
  $('#menu>li').each(function (x, i) {
   console.log(x, i)
    var li = $(i);
    if (!li.hasClass('active')) {
      var newHeight = li.height() <= 0 ? '40px' : '0';
      console.log('setting', newHeight);
      li.height(newHeight);
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

li {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li.active {
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="listElement active">Test me 1</li>
  <li class="listElement" style="padding-left:70px">Test me 2</li>
  <li class="listElement" style="padding-left:140px">Test me 3</li>
  <li class="listElement" style="padding-left:210px">Test me 4</li>
</ul>
```

By the way, it's not unexpected, It's just the text is overflowing because of div height is 0.